# Codename one - how to style the Overflow and its Commands in CSS

Tags: css, codenameone

So I have this overflow that I would like to give a white background but I have failed to get the overflow container so I can set its UIID for styling. I can't find where to set the UIID for the command either.

```
mainToolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu("Members", null, (e) -> {
    });
    mainToolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu("Groups", null, (e) -> {
    });
    mainToolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu("Share Holders", null, (e) -> {
    });
    mainToolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu("Fixed Deposits", null, (e) -> {
    });
    mainToolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu("Transactions", null, (e) -> {
    });
    mainToolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu("Reports", null, (e) -> {
    });
    mainToolbar.getOverflowButton().setUIID("OverFlowButton");
    mainToolbar.getOverflowButton().setIcon(materialIcon(FontImage.MATERIAL_MORE_VERT, 4, 0xffffff));
```

and here is the result;

[image: Overflow menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try styling the following UIIDs: `Menu`, `Command` and `CommandList`.

Notice you can use the Component Inspector tool to view the available styles in the current form. You need to refresh it after showing the overflow.

Comment: I can't see the Overflow menu in the ComponentInspector, even when doing as you described? The Inspector tool just show the Toolbar and the components in.

Comment: Overflow is a separate dialog not contained in the toolbar. If you refresh after it's shown you should see the dialog content in the hierarchy. Notice you won't see much since the overflow is a list with a renderer. That provides very limited information to the inspector

Comment: Thanks, but I don’t even see that. I can’t see any change at all in the inspector before/after showing the overflow menu and doing refresh. Seems like it may miss the menu somehow?

Comment: I just tested and I see this doesn't show. I don't think it's fixable for this case since overflow is indeed a special case component. As I said, it wouldn't give you too much anyway,

Comment: I agree it’s not a big issue, but it’s good to know it’s not a problem with my app or setup. Thanks